# Взаимодействие между компонентами Angular 2

Tags: angular2, компоненты

Есть два соседних компонента и сервис. По нажатию кнопки первого компонента второй компонент должен подгружать себе данные из сервиса. Как правильно это организовать?

Comment: как расположены эти компоненты в разметке?

Comment: по соседству друг с другом

Comment: сделай [mcve] как это сейчас выглядит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Первый компонент вызывает метод сервиса.
2. Сервис кидает в Observable какое-то значение.
3. Второй компонент, подписанный на этот Observable, что-то делает.

Вместо Observable можно использовать EventEmmiter.

Comment: а если сервис только внутренний? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, я не знаю, что такое _внутренний_ сервис.

Comment: экземпляр которого только внутри компонента создается :)

Comment: @Grundy, тогда надо менять эту архитектуру)))